# Beyond Compare for Object Instances

Tags: object, comparison

Does anyone know of a tool or library in .net that can be used to compare object properties and sub-objects like beyond compare does for text files? What I am looking for is a way to show two instances of the same type and show colored coded differences between them and allow the user to copy values between the objects.

Answer (score 4):

Using [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com/) you can compare objects with other objects or saved snapshots.

[image: Comparison sample]

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: serialize your objects into XML and run a [WinDiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDiff) or TortoiseSVN built-in diff-viewer.

1. The export can be done (with [Serializalbe] objects) with *XmlSerializer* or [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx):

   ```
   Person p1 = new Person("Zighetti", "Barbara", 101);
   FileStream writer = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
   DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person));
   ser.WriteObject(writer, p1);
   writer.Close();
   ```
2. Repeat this step for p2 (instance of Person).
3. Drop your xmls into WinDiff or your favorite diff viewer.

**Special XML diff tools**

- [XML diff online](http://tools.decisionsoft.com/xmldiff.html)
- [Using the XML Diff and Patch Tool in Your Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx)
- [XMLDiff](http://freshmeat.net/projects/xmldiff/)

Comment: Yes, serialize it, but serialize to an XmlWriter configured to do indentation. You might also need to do postprocessing to maintain a canonical order.